# передача параметров в запрос к drf

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

хочу написать парсер для api написанной на drf

```
import requests # Модуль для обработки URL
import time # Модуль для остановки программы

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/reg/'
    # Заголовки для передачи вместе с URL
data = {"user":"admin", "password":"admin"}

full_page = requests.get(url, data=data)
print(full_page.content)
```

но получаю ошибку  ,что не предоставил учетные данные. я понимаю что скорее всего неправильно их передаю в запрос `requests.get` . 
в представлении drf используется `@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))`.
при этом если я пишу такой запрос в консоли `curl -u admin:admin -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/reg/` все выводится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests # Модуль для обработки URL
import time # Модуль для остановки программы

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/reg/'

full_page = requests.get(url, auth=("admin","admin"))
print(full_page.content)
```